# Application using segment analytics throwing java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: INTERNET permission is required

Tags: robolectric, robolectric-gradle-plugin

Problem : I am trying to run test cases for my app using robolectric. My application is segment analytics. Its throwing Internet permission exception while its already there in my manifest file.

**robolectric version : 3.7.1,  targetSDKVersion : 26, gradle : 3.0.1**
    command : ./gradlew clean testBuildDebug

```
system : Mac.

build.gradle file:

flavorDimensions "default"

productFlavors {
  build {
    applicationId = "com.example"
  }
}

public class DeckardApplication extends Application {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Analytics analytics;
    Analytics.Builder builder = new Analytics.Builder(this, "xyz").trackApplicationLifecycleEvents();
    builder.logLevel(Analytics.LogLevel.VERBOSE);
    analytics = builder.build();

    if (analytics != null) {
      Analytics.setSingletonInstance(analytics);
    }
  }
}

@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class DeckardActivityTest {
  private DeckardActivity activity = null;

  @Before
  public void prepareActivity() {
    activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(DeckardActivity.class);
  }

  @Test
  public void testVisibility() {
    View text = activity.findViewById(R.id.text);
    TestUtility.checkViewVisible(text);
  }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:versionCode="2"
          android:versionName="1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
          package="com.example">
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application android:name=".DeckardApplication"
                 android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <activity android:name=".activity.DeckardActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
      <activity android:name=".common.TargetActivity"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71968990/6341943